# Is there a way to load a <class '_io.BufferedReader'> object using geopandas?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, python-packaging

I am trying to include shapefiles as package data in Python, and I'm having a tough time understanding what to do with the `stream` of data. Pandas' read_excel() and read_csv() work just fine, but when I try to access more complicated filetypes, I don't know what I should do:

```
CPLE_OpenFailedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
fiona/_shim.pyx in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector()

fiona/_err.pyx in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer()

CPLE_OpenFailedError: '/vsimem/234656ed68374e389c0c432547115bb1' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

The filetype being returned is a `<class '_io.BufferedReader'>` object. I expected geopandas.read_file() or fiona.open() to work on this, but I think I'm missing a critical step. Can geospatial data be loaded this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geopandas.read_file()` should normally open it with GeoPandas 0.9.0 or newer. The following snippet works on my end. If you have some specifics which do not work, try to expand your question with a minimal reproducible example.

```py
>>> import geopandas as gpd
>>> import io

>>> df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('nybb'))
>>> df.to_file('tst.json', driver="GeoJSON")

>>> f = io.open("tst.json", "rb")
>>> type(f)
_io.BufferedReader

>>> df = gpd.read_file(f)
```

Comment: I'm importing a shapefile rather than a json. Maybe the issue is that the stream is only grabbing the .shp file without the other files that come with (.cpg, .dbf, .prj, and .shx), because if I go ahead and save the file as a JSON using the GeoJSON driver, it works fine the way you suggest.

Comment: Yes, it will probably not work for shapefile due to its multi-file structure.

Comment: Got it - thanks for the input. Do you have any suggestions for what's standard when including shapefile data in a python package?

Comment: GeoPandas includes two shapefiles, you can check how it is done https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/tree/master/geopandas/datasets

Comment: Perfect, this is easy to implement. Their approach feels like it should be the generalized way to handle all package data. It doesn't require reformatting much code at all. Any idea why it isn't?

Comment: I have a vague memory that this solution causes an issue if you want to turn your script depending on geopandas to an executable or something like that. I can't find that discussion now. It is not a bulletproof solution.

Comment: It seems like it is the simplest approach for packages that aren't going to be that complex. Alright, thanks!